# CSS Float left fails to align div blocks correctly with IE10

Tags: css

I have two div blocks which should be aligned next to each other. 
The second block aligns perfectly next to the first block with ALL BROWSERS except Exploder, which shifts the second block down. I have tried setting the divs to inline-block, including the divs in another div and everything else I could think of, but nothing works.
You can see this at:
[clubaero.nl](http://club-aero.com)

CSS:

```
.leftbox {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    }

    .main1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "leftbox">
.... here is content of the 1st div .....
</div>

<div class = "main1">
.... here is content of the 2nd div ....
</div>
```

Comment: hahaha exploder, I like it!

Comment: Offhand, try removing margin: 0 auto; from .main1. And see if it's related to that.

Answer (score 2):

If you search your style sheet, you have the following style:

```
.row-fluid .span9 {width:74.46%;}
```

This is overriding your width of `700px;` for `.span9`.  If you change this to 700px it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You should never use auto if you are not sure what you are doing. Specifying auto tells the browser to automatically determine the left and right margins itself which can differ from browser to browser. Try removing margin: 0 auto; from .main1 as Matt also suggested and see if it works.

Also correct this :- `.row-fluid .span9 {width:74.46%;}`